# SQL numeric convert to datetime related query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following structure where id is unique and date is in numeric format

```
ID     Date
1     20130914
2     20130609
3     Null
4     20140614
5     Null
```

Can you help me with a query in which I can display the results as 
following

```
14-Sep-2013
```

Please help

Comment: [This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: This belongs to presentation layer, not to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

That's [format 112](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx):

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '20130914', 112) --date instead of datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select replace(CONVERT(varchar(11),cast('20130914' as datetime),106),' ','-')

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11),datefield,106),' ','-') FROM TableA
```

You could refer to [this article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) which lists of all available SQL Server Date Formats

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on Sql Server 2014 and 2012**

```
CREATE TABLE TESTDATES (DATEID INT IDENTITY(1,1), DATEVALUE int)

insert into TESTDATES(DATEVALUE) values(NULL);
insert into TESTDATES(DATEVALUE) values(20140614);


SELECT CONVERT(date, CAST(DATEVALUE AS NVARCHAR), 112) FROM TESTDATES WHERE DATEVALUE is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

USe this :

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Your column name containing date, '%d-%M-%Y') FROM YOURTABLENAME